# Burninate [usability]?

Tags: discussion, tags

**UPDATE** Sterling work by @[Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) and there are at present no Qs with this tag - issue is 'moot'.

---

Tag [usability](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability) lacks a Usage guide, has 3 followers and is currently applied to <s>14</s> 6 Open questions:

<s>Q: Can't “see” Gmail's “new look”?</s>
<s>Q: How do I disable zoom effect when hovering mouse over thumbnails in Google Image Search?</s>
<s>Q: How to add user to an existing post in Google Plus?</s>
Q: How to Change “me” in Gmail
Q: How to change the picture in the upper right corner in Gmail?
<s>Q: How to make to an existing public post private in Google Plus?</s>
<s>Q: Is there a way to change the 15-minute edit rule for comments on a Ning site?</s> 
<s>Q: Is there a way to stop Google sheets from telling me to use Ctrl C?</s>
Q: Link to a cell in a Google Spreadsheet via URL?
Q: Move a Facebook chat window horizontally
<s>Q: Quickly navigating to a date in Google Calendar</s>
Q: Shortcut for clearing a column on Tweetdeck
Q: Turn off smooth scrolling in Slack
<s>Q: Weird date display on Windows Live Calendar task view</s>

Regarding Shog9’s criteria for burnination, summarised as:

```
  - Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
  - Is it unambiguous?
  - Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
  - Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
  - Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
```

IMO the As are, in order: No, No, Yes, No, No.

It is a topic with experts (eg see the SE site: [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) but it appears current usage here has little connection with that site.
[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/usability) has this definition:

> The degree to which something is able or fit to be used.

which seems to imply a degree of subjectivity and hence potential conflict with the [primarily opinion-based](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) close reason.

Would anyone care to speak in its defence in a trial for its life?

Comment: Kill it with fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now there are 0 questions with this tag

Notes:

I'm pretty sure that there will not be arguments to keep  [usability](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability) and considering the ale's comment made four days ago (Kill it with fire), I removed the tag from the last questions that still had it.